# Minimum and max price between price range mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this table "prices"

```
id | price_per_week | date_start | date_end
1  | 500            | timestamp  | timestamp
1  | 5000           | timestamp  | timestamp
2  | 100            | timestamp  | timestamp
3  | 300            | timestamp  | timestamp
3  | 200            | timestamp  | timestamp
3  | 6000           | timestamp  | timestamp
3  | 50             | timestamp  | timestamp
4  | 600            | timestamp  | timestamp
5  | 800            | timestamp  | timestamp
5  | 200            | timestamp  | timestamp
```

I want to get all the ids where their min and max value are between a price range. for example all the ids that have  min price_per_week >=  200 and max price_per_week 1000.

When I run this query

```
SELECT id FROM prices WHERE price_per_week BETWEEN 200 AND 1000
```

it returns also the id 1,3 which have a max price_per_week greater than 1000

I think I should use subqueries somehow, but I am still learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want id's whose weekly price is always inside the range, try think like this:

"Show me id's that do not belong to set that have price out of range"

```
SELECT id 
FROM prices 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM prices
  WHERE price_per_week not between 200 and 1000
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple rows with the same id, so this could be the problem. your query select **every** row with price_per_week between 200 and 1000.

Comment: Yes but each id can have multiple rows where a price is defined for a period of time. This is for a holiday rentals site where the homes have rates for a period of time

Comment: you could add something like `AND date_start <= someStartDate AND date_end >= someEndDate` if you want the results for a special period.

Comment: No I don't want that. I just want all the ids between a price range independent of date

Comment: i'm sorry, i think i didn't understand your question the last time. so you want the ids of all entries where the price_per_week is between a certain range in **every** period? so this could be `SELECT id FROM prices WHERE price_per_week BETWEEN 200 AND 1000 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM prices WHERE price_per_week NOT BETWEEN 200 AND 1000)` (haven't tested yet...)